# Regex for specific URL path

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to match a URL's path (window.location.pathname) but exclude anything further down the path.

I want to match the following:

- /admin/sites/{2-6 digit number}{/ exclude the rest}

Examples

/admin/sites/123 - true

/admin/sites/1 - false

/admin/sites/123/foo - false

I've got as far as the following regex but can't seem to figure out the rest.

```
/admin\/sites\/[0-9]/.test(window.location.pathname)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^\/admin\/sites\/\d{2,6}$/
```

the `$` anchors the expression to the end of the string so it must *end* with the digits.

I also included the `^` so it must *start* with `/admin`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match up to the `/` after the digits, you need the following regex:

```
^\/admin\/sites\/[0-9]{2,6}(?=\/)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE3pB9/1)

Comment: Actually, I was in two minds since your question and provided code differ. In case you need more help, feel free to drop a comment.